# Getting an error on clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear

Tags: objective-c

I recently copied Apple's master detail template to my own project, but I get an error with this line of code:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = self.splitViewController.isCollapsed; //ERROR ON THIS LINE it says "Property 'clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear` not found on object type 'MasterViewController *'"
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

It didn't get an error in Apple's template. Please help!

Here's the `MasterViewController` declaration:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h> 
@class DetailViewController; 

@interface MasterViewController : UIViewController 
@property (strong, nonatomic) DetailViewController *detailViewController; 
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView; 
@end
```

Comment: Can you post the code declaring `MasterViewController`? It looks as if `MasterViewController` does not have the `clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear` property. Normally, that property is there for a `UICollectionViewController`.

Comment: The .h file `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class DetailViewController;

@interface MasterViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) DetailViewController *detailViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@end
`

Comment: `clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear` is a property of UITableViewController not UIViewController.  https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewcontroller/1614758-clearsselectiononviewwillappear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your declaration for `MasterViewController` does not show a `clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear` property. Which is why you get the error you mentioned. My suspicion is that in the original code where you based your code off of `MasterViewController` was extending `UITableViewController` or `UICollectionViewController` instead of `UIViewController`. Check the original template to see how `MasterViewController` was declared. I believe it should be `UITableViewController` if it was the standard Master Detail template in Xcode.

Or, your code is referring to the wrong view controller. I can't tell you for sure without knowing all the details.

Comment: Just open up xcode, and press new xcode project, select "Master View" as the option.

Comment: See the change I made above to my answer - I believe what you need to do is extend `MasterViewController` from `UITableViewController`.